Randomly unable to launch mysql-workbench-community
I have been having on and off issues having mysql-workbench work. It randomly does and doesn't work. When I try from the menu and it's not working, nothing happens. When I try to run it from the terminal I some times get the error below. What is strange is that normally if I run the command a few times, it starts working. Today however no matter how many times I try to run it I get the same error. I would completely remove and re-install it but I have a lot of hosts saved in it.
dovid@dovid-desktop:~$ mysql-workbench-community 
Using /snap/mysql-workbench-community/15/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.
Gtk-Message: 01:03:26.175: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.

(mysql-workbench-bin:1258612): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:03:26.190: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2:21: Failed to import: Error opening file /home/dovid/snap/mysql-workbench-community/15/.config/gtk-3.0/colors.css: No such file or directory

(mysql-workbench-bin:1258612): GLib-WARNING **: 01:03:27.202: GError set over the top of a previous GError or uninitialized memory.
This indicates a bug in someone's code. You must ensure an error is NULL before it's set.
The overwriting error message was: Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Operation not permitted)
/snap/mysql-workbench-community/15/usr/bin/mysql-workbench: line 108: 1258612 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $MWB_BINARIES_DIR/mysql-workbench-bin "$@"

When I try to run the binary directly I get
dovid@dovid-desktop:~$ /snap/mysql-workbench-community/current/usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin
/snap/mysql-workbench-community/current/usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlide.so.8.0.38: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dovid@dovid-desktop:~$ 

however I do seem to have those modules
dovid@dovid-desktop:~$ locate libsqlide.so
/snap/mysql-workbench-community/15/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libsqlide.so
/snap/mysql-workbench-community/15/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libsqlide.so.8.0.38
dovid@dovid-desktop:~$ 

EDIT: Trying to use the deb package from their web site did not work either
dovid@dovid-desktop:~$ strace /usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin
execve("/usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin", ["/usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin"], 0x7ffe813e75b0 /* 51 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55dce21d1000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffcbff3dc90) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=206940, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 206940, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fec2c484000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=16384, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/haswell", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=192512, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/haswell/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls/haswell", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls", 0x7ffcbff3cee0)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/haswell/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/haswell/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/haswell", 0x7ffcbff3cee0)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/haswell/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/haswell", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7ffcbff3cee0)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/haswell/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/haswell/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/haswell/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/haswell", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffcbff3cee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libsqlide.so.8.0.38", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0
writev(2, [{iov_base="/usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin", iov_len=28}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="error while loading shared libra"..., iov_len=36}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="libsqlide.so.8.0.38", iov_len=19}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="cannot open shared object file", iov_len=30}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="No such file or directory", iov_len=25}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 10/usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlide.so.8.0.38: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
) = 147
exit_group(127)                         = ?
+++ exited with 127 +++


Are you sure you are using MySQL 8? MySQL 5.7 and lower do NOT mix with Workbench for MySQL 8 and neither does Workbench for v5 for MySQL 8. If you do: libsqlide.so is not in the Ubuntu packages so you might need to ask on a mysql/workbench support forum. libsqlide.so.8.0.38 is only for MySQL 8 and Workbench 8

I am getting the same issue. I was using snap package. Since then I have uninstalled snap and installed .deb package from mysql website.
I think it's because the newer version doesn't support Ubuntu 20.04 anymore but I might be wrong since snap is basically a container and this shouldn't be an issue.

Were you able to export your configs or did you need to star from scratch?

This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. Please UPVOTE the question to show support for the question. The more people do the more attention the system will give it

@DovidBender I started from scratch. I raised it as an issue on github for it. The maintainer reverted it to previous version for now.
You may also revert it manually with the following command: sudo snap revert mysql-workbench-community

@DarkDead That does not work for me, I believe because I removed it completely.  What do you get when you do sudo snap info mysql-workbench-community and sudo snap list mysql-workbench-community ?
